# How do I get rid of the search suggestions in Chrome?

Tags: chrome-for-android, search

I want to remove these suggestions on chrome for android, but I cannot find how to do it anywhere. Can someone help me with this?

Once I type a letter the normal suggestions appear. I just don't want to see all these recent searches I made.

[image]

Comment: They seem to be from your history. I don't see a toggle to turn off history suggestions in Chrome.

Comment: Sadly, there doesn't seem to be any way to do this without turning off History or using incognito mode.

Answer (score 1):

Those are suggestions that you can turn off.

1. Go to the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
2. Click Settings.
3. Click Show advanced settings (on the bottom)
4. In the Privacy section, deselect the "Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar" checkbox.